# No Virtual constructors but virtual destructor

Tags: oop, constructor, virtual-destructor

If we dont have virtual constructors then why we have virtual destructors? Can constructors also be virtual?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we not have a virtual constructor in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733360/why-do-we-not-have-a-virtual-constructor-in-c)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: I think the question is rather, why do we have virtual destructors in C++?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- There is no point in virtual constructor - you declare exactly what
  type is created, and it is well known in compile time. The compiler
  do not need [and actually cannot, since the dynamic dispatch is based
  on information which is created only after the object was created].
  So **there are no virtual constructors**.
- Virtual destructors are important to prevent memory leaks, and
  monitor the system. Assume you have `A* a = new B;` [`B` inherits
  from `A`], and you later `delete a;` - the compiler has no way of
  knowing `a` is a `B` [in the general case], and will invoke `A`'s
  destructor - if it wasn't virtual, and you might get a memory leak,
  or other faults.
- Using virtual destructor - you **ensure that `B`'s destructor is
  invoked, since a `B` object is being destroyed**.

Comment: I didn't understand the first point . can you elaborate it, please.

Comment: @jhamb: When you invoke a constructor - it is something like `new MyClass;`. The *dynamic type* and the *static type* of the created object - are exactly the same, the real concrete object.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual destructors are needed because at destruction time, you don't always know what type you're dealing with:

```
Base *make_me_an_object()
{
    if (the_moon_is_full())
        return new Derived();
    else
        return new Base();
}

int main()
{
    Base *p = make_me_an_object();
    delete p;
}
```

The `delete` in the above program's `main` doesn't know whether its `p` points to a `Base` or a `Derived` object, but if the `Base` destructor is `virtual` (as it should be), then `delete` can use `*p`'s [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) to find the right destructor.

By contrast, at construction time, you always know what kind of object you're creating. (And in case you don't, then you can create a factory or "[virtual constructor](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8)" that does know.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class base {
   protected:
    int a;
};
class derived : public base {

};
int main() {
    base * pointer_of_base = new derived;
    delete pointer_of_base; // this will delete the base calss not the derived

}
```

The constructors are called on one time when we create the object of the class so when we  inherit the base class constructors calls only one time so no need to be virtual.

But when we accessing the derived class from the pointer of the base class, if we want to delete the object of derived class we delete it by the pointer of base class but delete(pointer_of_base) will call the destructor of the base class but the actual motto is to delete the derived class . thus we need the destructor be virtual in nature.