# Constructors and destructor must be virtual?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, destructor

Exists some differences between a constructor or destructor be virtual or not? In this case, what should be done

```
class A {
public:
    A();
    ~A();
}
```

or

```
class A {
public:
    virtual A();
    virtual ~A();
}
```

Have isocpp fot this case?

Thanks...

Comment: Constructor: cannot be done. Destructor: it depends. See [*when to use virtual destructors?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have Virtual constructor in C++ [why no virtual Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733360/why-do-we-not-have-a-virtual-constructor-in-c).

Virtual destructors are useful when you can delete an instance of a derived class through a pointer to base class. Refer to [When to use Virtual Destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors).

Answer (score 1):

You can't have virtual constructors, but a virtual destructor makes it possible to destroy an object through a base class pointer while calling the derived destructors apropriately.

For example, **dont actually run this code**

```
class A {
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() {}
    virtual ~B() {}
};

class C : public B {
public:
    C() : _p( new int(0) ) {}
    ~C() { delete _p; std::cout << "Deleted p" << std::endl; }
private:
    int *_p;
};


int main() {
    C *c1 = new C();
    C *c2 = new C();

    B *bPointer = c1;
    A *aPointer = c2;

    std::cout << "Deleting through B*" << std::endl;
    delete bPointer; // "deleted p"
    std::cout << "------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Deleting through A*" << std::endl;
    delete aPointer; // No output

    return 0;
}
```

Class A's destructor should've been marked as virtual. You only need to write virtual on the topmost class of the hierarchy.

Comment: I'd say he should run it for learning purposes :) But not use it in production code!