# What's the difference between Prototype design pattern and copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am trying to understand when I should use Prototype design pattern.
Here is example of Prototype as I understand it:

```
class Prototype
{
public:
    virtual Prototype* clone() = 0;
...
};

class ConcretePrototype : public Prototype
{
public:
    Prototype* clone() override { ... }
};

// Usage:
ConcretePrototype proto;
auto protPtr = proto.clone();
```

Where is a question:
Why this better than:

```
class Obj
{
public:
    Obj();

    Obj(const Obj&);
    Obj& operator = (const Obj& other);
};

Obj o;
Obj o2 = o;
```

So when should I actually use Prototype?

Comment: the code `class ConcretePrototype` has to be extended by the `: public Prototype` code

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ One is grey. The other, if you have any taste at all, is not. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Copy constructor is an element of the language.

Prototype is a design pattern used to spawn (polymorphic) objects basing on some existing instance.

It would be difficult to use the former to implement the latter as copy constructor is intended to be used when knowing exact instance of the object, while prototype is used when there could be *any* possible implementation of some interface and you just want to obtain new object of exactly the same implementation, without resorting to some weird casting and checking methods.

Lets assume that you have Interface `I` and implementations `A` and `B`. At some point you are given object `i` implementing `I`. Perhaps you would not want to modify it, instead you would prefer to obtain new instance and then introduce some modification to it. How could that be achieved, when you don't know exact class of `i`? Prototype pattern is one solution to that problem: `I* i2 = i.clone();`.

Comment: Yeah, this is really great explanation. Thanks!

Comment: This is very helpful while working with immutable types. Every time, you want to change a field you will have to create a new type cloning from the first type and then apply the change.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a reference from GoF book:

> clients that clone the prototype don't have to know about their concrete subclasses. Clients should never need to downcast the return value of Clone to the desired type.

[image: Example of Prototype design pattern]

From your example, the client is NOT aware of (or cannot access) `ConcretePrototype`.

```
// Usage:
SomeMethod(PrototypeInterface iproto) // Thanks Prototype pattern
{
  // ConcretePrototype proto;     
  auto protPtr = iproto.clone(); // Gets correct object without calling concrete object's constructor explicitly.
}
```

Hope you understood the situation when this pattern is useful. Also Remember, there is [no virtual constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733360/why-do-we-not-have-a-virtual-constructor-in-c).