# Force subclasses to implement a certain constructor prototype in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism

Suppose I have an abstract class `A`. Is it possible for A to force any classes inheriting from it to implement a certain constructor prototype?

e.g.:

```
class A {
public:
    // purely virtual function
    virtual void func() = 0;
    // what i would like to be able to do
    virtual A(Obj) = 0;
};
```

While the purely virtual function `func` above is legal, the constructor `A(Obj)` cannot be virtual. I would like if instances of a class `B` inheriting from `A` will remain abstract (or some uninstantiable or erroneous equivalent) until `B` overrides the constructor `A(Obj)`.

In other words, I want to force any subclass of `A` to implement a constructor that takes an `Obj` as an argument. Is this possible?

Comment: Does `A` hold on to the `Obj`?  Also you say `std::string` and then switch back to `Obj`.  Which on is it?

Comment: Have you looked at "[Why do we not have a virtual constructor in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/733360/1460794)"

Comment: Sorry, edited :) A may or may not hold on to Obj, I don't mind about that, I just want to make sure that a constructor exists in subclasses of A that take an Obj as a parameter

Comment: Why do you want that ?

Comment: Where or how do you want `Obj` to be used? It wouldn't make much sense to force the parameter to be there if you don't do something with it. And wherever you do something with it will force the parameter to be there. Maybe you are worried that the chicken will arrive without the egg ever existing?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Maybe if you explain the thing you are trying to achieve we can give you a better option.

Comment: It's for a class called `Serializable`: I want any subclasses of `Serializable` to be able to create a serialized `Archive` of the class, and also be constructed from a serialized `Archive`. So the constructor would be `Serializable(Archive);`

Comment: The compiler will probably complain about any missing constructor in the subclass if you try to call it through inheritance. I see this as a good way to force subclasses to implement what is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a subclass is free to implement any kind of a constructor that it wants.

The only responsibility a subclass's constructor has is to construct its superclasses.

So, it is possible for a superclass to influence, in a minor way, how its subclasses' constructors work. For example, if a class's constructor takes a parameter that's an instance of a class's inner class (a minor variation of your edited code example), the subclass is then required to instantiate the inherited inner class, in order to construct its superclass, **or take an existing instance as a parameter**, that it forwards to the superclass's constructor.

But that's, pretty much, as far as it goes. The subclass's constructors' signatures are completely out of the superclass's control.