How to overload a procedure declared in an abstract type in fortran?
In the following module, an abstract type (Base_Arrays_class) is declared and two types are derived (One_Array_t and Two_Arrays_t). In the abstract type, there is a procedure abstract_init deferred to init.
In the derived types, the subroutines one_array_init and two_arrays_init are used to init the array(s).
module my_mod
    implicit none

    type, abstract :: Base_Arrays_class
        integer :: array_size
        real,dimension(:), allocatable :: array
    contains
        procedure(abstract_init), deferred :: init
    end type  Base_Arrays_class

    abstract interface
        subroutine abstract_init(this,array_size)
            import Base_Arrays_class
            class(Base_Arrays_class), intent(inout) :: this
            integer, intent(in) :: array_size
        end subroutine abstract_init
    end interface

    type, extends(Base_Arrays_class) :: One_Array_t
    contains
        procedure :: init => one_array_init
    end type One_Array_t

    type, extends(Base_Arrays_class) :: Two_Arrays_t
        real,dimension(:), allocatable :: second_array
    contains
        procedure :: init => two_arrays_init
    end type Two_Arrays_t

contains

    subroutine one_array_init(this,array_size)
        class(One_Array_t), intent(inout) :: this
        integer, intent(in) :: array_size
        
        this%array_size=array_size
        allocate(this%array(array_size))
        this%array=1.0
    end subroutine one_array_init
    
    subroutine two_arrays_init(this,array_size)
        class(Two_Arrays_t), intent(inout) :: this
        integer, intent(in) :: array_size
        
        this%array_size=array_size
        allocate(this%array(array_size), this%second_array(array_size))
        this%array=2.0
        this%second_array=3.0
    end subroutine two_arrays_init

end module my_mod

Below, an example of program that uses this module.
program pgm
    use my_mod
    implicit none
    
    type(One_Array_t) :: one_array
    type(Two_Arrays_t) :: two_arrays
    integer :: i, size
    
    size = 4    
    call one_array%init(size)
    call two_arrays%init(size)
    
    print *,"one_array"
    do i=1,size
        print *, one_array%array(:)
    end do
    
    print *,"two_arrays"
    do i=1,size
        print *, two_arrays%array(:)
    end do
    print *
    do i=1,size
        print *, two_arrays%second_array(:)
    end do

end program pgm

It works perfectly.
But now, I would like to overload init to choose the init value(s). For example :
call one_array%init(size,4) and call two_arrays%init(size, 5,8).
So, overload of init is needed. Something like that (for One_Array_t) :
  interface init
     module procedure one_array_init, one_array_init2
  end interface init

But, it does not conform to abstract_init and I could not be able to do this overload.
Is it possible or not ?
Thanks for answers.

Look into Generic

@ian Bush. Thanks for this idea. I did not think about it. I will try. Did you have an example ?

@ian Bush. I tried and I got the following error message : Undefined specific binding 'one_array_init2' as target of GENERIC 'init'

Can't you just go the entirely boring route of one_array%init(size,[4]) and two_arrays%init(size,[5,8])?

@francescalus. In this specific case, I can do that with zero size array. But, to be more generic, is it possible to overload a procedure declared in an abstract type ?

A specific type-bound procedure is overriden, not overloaded, and a generic type-bound procedure of a type cannot have the same name as a specific type-bound procedure of that type.

@Franceslacu. So is it possible or not, to do what I asked ?

It's not possible to overload init, because init is a specific procedure not a generic procedure.

@francescalus. Thanks for answer. So, to do an init procedure overload, is there another solution ?

Is it really necessary to make the init routine to be "virtual" (= a type-bound procedure of the parent/abstract type)? https://stackoverflow.com/a/733393/3501546

@roygvib. In this example, constructor is used but it could be another subroutine, not necessarily the init

How about defining type-bound procedures init1 and init2 with different signatures and setting a generic name init to them in the parent/base type, and then overriding one of init1 and init2 in child types...?

As mentioned in the comments, I also think we can use generic for this purpose, but it may be necessary to use it in the parent type, eg...
module test_m
    implicit none

    type, abstract :: Parent_t
    contains
        generic   :: sub => sub1, sub2
        procedure :: sub1 => Parent_sub1
        procedure :: sub2 => Parent_sub2
    endtype

    type, extends(Parent_t) :: Child1_t
    contains
        procedure :: sub1 => Child1_sub1
    endtype

    type, extends(Parent_t) :: Child2_t
    contains
        procedure :: sub2 => Child2_sub2
    endtype

contains

    subroutine Parent_sub1(this, n)
        class(Parent_t) :: this
        integer :: n
        stop "sub1 not implemented"
    end
    subroutine Parent_sub2(this, n1, n2)
        class(Parent_t) :: this
        integer :: n1, n2
        stop "sub2 not implemented"
    end

    subroutine Child1_sub1(this, n)
        class(Child1_t) :: this
        integer :: n
        print *, "Child1: n = ", n
    end
    subroutine Child2_sub2(this, n1, n2)
        class(Child2_t) :: this
        integer :: n1, n2
        print *, "Child2: n1, n2 = ", n1, n2
    end
end module

program main
    use test_m
    implicit none
    type(Child1_t) :: c1
    type(Child2_t) :: c2

    call c1 % sub( 100 )
    call c2 % sub( 1, 2 )

    !! call c1 % sub( 1, 2 )  !! stop
    !! call c2 % sub( 100 )   !! stop
end

(can be tested in this page)
Here, I did not use abstract interface for the parent type, such that only one procedure of interest (e.g. sub1) can be implemented in a child type. (If necessary, both sub1 and sub2 can be defined in a child type.) A new routine like sub3() can also be added later in the parent type.
Another approach may be not to use overloading, but (as also mentioned in the comments), just to define a single routine that receives a more "general" argument (like arrays, derived types, etc).
(By the way, if init() is used as a "constructor" (or "initializer"), I usually do not make it "virtual" in the parent type but directly define it in each child type, if the concrete type is known for initialization and the signature of init() can be different among different child types. For comparison, this Q/A for C++ might also be related.)
